# How to understand `operating system packet filtering layer`?

Tags: networking, iptables, operating-systems, kubernetes

When I read this document [#kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy):

> kube-proxy uses the operating system packet filtering layer if there is one and it's available. Otherwise, `kube-proxy` forwards the traffic itself.

so, what's the `operating system packet filtering layer` in there? is it means the iptables/netfilter network component in OS kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on Linux systems this would be `iptables`. However, Kubernetes can also run on BSD and even Windows (for worker nodes), which obviously don't have `iptables`, but `pf` and Windows Firewall.

The slightly vague wording comes from the fact that they can't name a single packet filter implementation because of these different operating system's implementation of it.